# Get error on sending JSON from JavaScript to Java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, servlets

I want to send some data from JavaScript to Java servlet with help of JSON. But I have problem with it.

This is my JavaSript code:

```
var myData = {"someNumber":34,"someDate":"May 22, 2014 12:00:00 AM","expiryDate":"May 29, 2014 12:00:00 AM","anotherNumber":3,"customerNumber":56,"name":"John Dow","type":"notype","someSize":"XXL","noMonth":11,"notes":"some notes here","colour":"Black"};
$.ajax({
            url :           "customerAdd",
            type:           "get",
            data:           {"myData" : JSON.stringify(myData)},
            contentType:    "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:       "json",
            async:          false,
            success:        function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
            },
            error:          function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("jqXHR: " + textStatus);
                console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus);
                console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

This is my Java code:

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{    
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Customer customer = gson.fromJson(request.getParameter("myData"), Customer.class);
        System.out.println(customer.toString());
    }
```

In result I get an error in JavaScript:

```
"textStatus: parsererror"
"errorThrown: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"
```

What's wrong with my code?

P.S.
I create myData in JavaScript by this way:

```
var myData = {  
                someNumber:    + $("#someNumber").val(),
                someDate:       $("#someDate").val(),
                expiryDate:     $("#expiryDate").val(),
                anotherNumber:      + $("#anotherNumber").val(),
                customerNumber: + $("#customerNumber").val(),
                name:           $("#name").val(),
                type:           $("#type").val(),
                someSize:        $("#someSize").val(),
                noMonth:        + $("#noMonth").val(),
                notes:          $("#notes").val(),
                colour:         $("#colour").val() };
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a JSON.stringify exemple :

```
JSON.stringify({x: 5, y: 6}); // '{"x":5,"y":6}'
```

You should remove the quots on the name of parameters, or could use a javascript object.

You should create your object like that :

```
var myData = new Object();
mydata.someNumber = $("#someNumber").val();
...
```

edit :

It's seems your trying to get a response in the ajax call, but your java code doesn't response anything, maybe you may try to debug it. and try to see if the java code is triggered ?

Comment: I've created my object as you suggested but unfortunately I received the same error.

Comment: new edit : you should try to remove the msg attribute in the success function prototype if your java code is triggered

Comment: I had removed msg attribute, but it didn't help. My java code doesn't response anything. But java code correctly parse received JSON data and does `System.out.println(customer.toString());` without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try

```
JSON.stringify({ "myData" : myData })
```

Comment: assuming that your myData object is valid I think you should be able to do this :

$.ajax({
            url :           "customerAdd",
            type:           "get",
            data:           JSON.stringify({ "myData": myData } ),

etc.

Comment: when you create your myData object some of the values have  + and some don't, do you need these ?

Comment: I added + to make a numeric values. I have removed + but it didn't help. I received the same error.

Comment: did you try changing  data: {"myData" : JSON.stringify(myData)},  to  data: JSON.stringify({"myData": myData}),

Comment: I changed data to `data:JSON.stringify({"myData" : myData})`. In result I think GET request became incorrect `http://localhost:8080/customerAdd?{%22myData%22:{%22magicNumber%22:%2234%22,%22someDate%22:%22May%2022,...}}` and now I receive another error: `errorThrown: Internal Server Error`.

Comment: change to a post request

Comment: I had changed to POST but in result I received `Internal Server Error` on the client side. And java couldn't parse this JSON request so I got `java.lang.NullPointerException` error on the server side.

Comment: yes, you'd need to implement doPost in your java servlet. But it does seem like there is something wrong with your data. The hard coded example of myData you gave in your example is ok, you can paste it into jsonlint.com and it validates. But the myData your generating from the jquery nodes may be invalid somehow. Use the developer tools in your browser to what is being sent to the servlet and try to validate it in jsonlint

Comment: I had validated my JSON request from developer tools in jsonlint.com as you suggested and It told me that It was "Valid JSON". And java parse it without any errors.

Comment: I just looked at the error message again  "errorThrown: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"  this is actually an error in the json which is being returned by the java servlet, NOT the json being sent by the javascript

Answer (score 1):

I've found my mistake. I shouldn't put

```
dataType: "json",
```

attribute in $.ajax, because I don't expect JSON data back from server.
I've just removed it.

Thank you Lee Bee and Tony for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

If the servlet method is not returning any json content to ajax, remove the

dataType: "json", from ajax call in javascript.